# how to disable gorm.mapping id generation per environment

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I work with an oracle db in production, for which I have mappings in gorm with id generator by sequences.

But now I want to disable all the mappings for the domains only in development where I use a hsqldb in file.

This is for not to have to install oracle for every developer pc.

I had tried with this in a BootStrap:

```
import grails.util.GrailsUtil;

class DevBootStrap {

    def grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->
        if(GrailsUtil.environment in ["development"]){
            grailsApplication.domainClasses.each { domainClass ->
                domainClass.metaClass.mapping = null
            }
        }
    }

    def destroy = {

    }

}
```

But it doesn't work.

I also tried with

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = null
```

And doesn't work either.

I think maybe something in _Events. But I don't know which event.

Can you give me any pointer?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this might work, however you need to add `.clazz`, otherwise you are playing around in the wrong classes.

```
grailsApplication.domainClasses.each { domainClass ->
    domainClass.clazz.metaClass.mapping = null
}
```

I am not sure, whether the point in time, when you change the mapping is early enough.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you can access the current environment in the domain class mappings with Environment.current. So in each of your domain classes you could try adding:

```
static mapping = {
    if ( Environment.current != Environment.DEVELOPMENT ) {
        //define mapping 
    }
}
```